# Writing a c-string directly into a std::string

Tags: c++, string

I want to get a log message from a C library. The library provides two functions :

```
int get_log_length(); // Returns the length of the string, including the terminating null character
void get_log(char *buffer); // Writes the log into buffer
```

I want to write that log into a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and return it. The normal way (I think) would be :

```
std::string get_log() {
    int length = get_log_length();
    char *buffer = new char[length];
    get_log(buffer);
    std::string str(buffer, length - 1);
    delete[] buffer;
    return str;
}
```

But I would like to skip using a `buffer`, so I thought of doing this :

```
std::string get_log() {
    std::string str;
    str.reserve(get_log_length());
    get_log(str.data()); // Bad: undefined behaviour
    return str;
}
```

But the [`size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) of the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) would remain unchanged, and would result in undefined behaviour (cf. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data)).

Is there a way to only write the log once ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to `resize` the string instead of `reserve`:

```
std::string get_log() {
   std::string str;
   str.resize(get_log_length());
   get_log(str.data());
   return str;
}
```

This will update the string's underlying buffer to the appropriate size AND fill the string out with `'\0'` characters. Afterwards, those characters are overwritten by `get_log`

One thing to be wary of, though, is that `get_log` is likely going to try to write a `\0` terminator to the string, which is not what you want in a `std::string`, so you may need to lop the last character off.

OR, the other way around; `get_log_length()` might return the size of the log message minus the terminating character (like `strlen` would), but `get_log` might try to write a terminating `'\0'` anyway, meaning that you'd need to size you string as `get_log_length() + 1`, and then afterwards `str.pop_back` to remove the terminator. Just double check this behavior.

Comment: The easiest way to avoid the extra `\0` is to do `.resize(get_log_length()-1)`, rather than resizing the string later. Then `get_log` is going to overwrite the existing null-terminator instead of adding a new one.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah that's a possibility. There's always chance for these kinds of off-by-one errors when going from C strings to C++ std::strings

Comment: `data()` is not an option regardless. Not only is it `const char *` but writing to the buffer is undefined behavior even if you `const_cast` it, as the OP already pointed out.

Comment: @EuroMicelli: `data()` has a non-const overload in C++17

Comment: @EuroMicelli: And it was admittedly a little late in coming; `vector` had a non-const `data` function since C++11. Writing to the buffer returned by the non-const overload is not UB

Comment: @AndyG, interesting, thank you. I wasn’t aware of that change. It would be good to specify the version caveat in your answer. I don’t think there is a standard-conforming way to do what the OP asks for in earlier versions.

Comment: @EuroMicelli yes, there is: `&str[0]` instead of `str.data()`. From C++11 onward, this is guaranteed to work ok. In practice, it will work in most implementations of earlier versions, too